# How do you manage CSRF tokens if your server scales horizontally and you can't predict where your client requests will go?

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

Say you have an application that is being served out of a Node instance, a CSRF token is applied in a cookie and all requests from the client must contain that token to be accepted.

If you're using a PM2 cluster, or your application is part of an AWS auto-scale group and where you are unable to guarantee that the request will go to the same server where the token originated, what happens and how do you manage that?

Comment: Follow up question: should you still be using CSRF tokens in 2018?